# VBA Macro code to copy multiple charts from Excel to Words and save them in different docs

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-charts

I do have an Excel file with multiple tabs in it. Each tab is tagged with a different referenced number and i would like to copy a chart contained in each WrkSht and paste it in different Word files, saving each word File with the tab name. Thanks!

```
    Sub ExportchART()

Dim Wrdapp As Word.Application
Dim Wrddoc As Word.document
Dim Chrobj As ChartObject
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet

Set Wrdapp = New Word.Application
Wrdapp.Visible = True
Wrdapp.Activate

Set Wrddoc = Wrdapp.Documents.Add
    For Each WrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    WrkSht.Activate
        For Each Chrobj In WrkSht.ChartObjects
            Chrobj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
            With Wrdapp.Selection
                .PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEobject
            End With
    
        Wrdapp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Add
        
        Wrdapp.Selection.Goto What:=wdGotoPage, Which:=wdgotonext
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Next Chrobj
Next WrkSht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub ExportCharts()
Dim WrdApp As New Word.Application, WrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim Chrobj As ChartObject, WrkSht As Worksheet
WrdApp.Visible = True
For Each WrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
  For Each Chrobj In WrkSht.ChartObjects
    Chrobj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
    WrdDoc.Characters.Last.PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject
  Next Chrobj
  WrdDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & WrkSht.Name & ".docx", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  WrdDoc.Close False
Next WrkSht
WrdApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work as it stops by the Wrd.Doc.SaveAS2.

Comment: Code revised. Try it now.